# ICommand Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, icommand

I have a strange issue of getting null exception. I created class that implements ICommand interface, I have two methods.

```
public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    NavigateAsync();
}

private async void NavigateAsync()
{
    await App.MainNavigation.PushAsync(new Pages.SettingsPage());
}
```

When NavigateAsync() is exectude my MainNavigation is always null, even that I can see that parameter inside Execute is set.

In my App.xaml.cs file I have created  public static INavigation MainNavigation { get; set; }

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        public static ViewModels.MainViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
        public static INavigation MainNavigation { get; set; }

        public App ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Paperboy.MainPage());
        }

        protected override void OnStart ()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }

        protected override void OnSleep ()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume ()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
```

Se when clicking icon i can se that command is executed but App.MainNavigation inside NavigateAsync() in null. So command is not executing PushAsync to SettingsPage.

Comment: Where  are you instancing/assigning the `MainNavigation` property?

Comment: @SushiHangover thx :) I totaly forgot to create instance of it inside mainpage :) Thx again!

Comment: No problem, MOR' Coffee time ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You never instantiate your `static MainNavigation` property...
If I can give you 2 remarks:

- instead of using a static property declared into your App.xaml.cs, maybe a better implementation could be to embed a Navigation getter into a specific 'service' class or directly into your Command definition:

  ```
  public class MyCommand : ICommand
  {
      ...

      // Navigation getter
      // There are better places for this prop but it's better
      // than in app.xaml.cs
      private INavigation MainNavigation
      {
          get => Application.Current?.MainPage?.Navigation;
      }

      public void Execute(object parameter)
      {
           NavigateAsync();
      }

      private async void NavigateAsync()
      {
          try
          {
              await MainNavigation?.PushAsync(new Pages.SettingsPage());
          }
          catch(){ ... }
      }
  }
  ```
- Another point I would like to note, is that your Command looks like asynchronous. Maybe you already know, but here is a good implementation of async commands to avoid app crashes: [Asynchronous commands](https://johnthiriet.com/async-command/)

I hope it can help you. Happy coding !